# How to not toggle all menus at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Boostrap for the first time ever, please don't kill me :D 
I have a problem with my navigation bar. I have 7 menus, each with a dropdown of its own. The problem is that when I click on a menu, they all dropdown at the same time, and I need only to dropdown the one I clicked on. My JS code is pretty rudimentary. 
This is what I used so far:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });
```

And the HTML code is this, (example for one menu; each menu has a similar code):

```
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Organizare <b class="caret"></b</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Conducere</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Consiliu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Departamente</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Administratie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Secretariat</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

What do I need to change so that only the menu I click on dropdown ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your selector is probably just too general, you'll need to set it to work in base of a parent container so it knows that you refer to the one you clicked and not to all that share the same class name.

Comment: Doesn't bootstrap handle the toggle for you? `$('.dropdown-menu')` selects every element with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the menu following the toggle:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/YXKzGm

Comment: p.s. And fix that broken closing `</b>`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple menus, I prefer to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
        $(this).next('dropdown-menu').slideDown();
    );
});
```

The advantage to this is that it will close any other open dropdown menus and then open the one that has been clicked.
It can be further improved to check if the .dropdown-toggle that was clicked is currently open.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the handler you're registering will select anything with the class `dropdown-menu`, then toggle it, because you've written:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });
```

As you say, you don't want to toggle everything with that class, you just want to toggle what was clicked, so you should use the [event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) parameter from [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to find what's been clicked, and select the relevent dropdown-menu to toggle:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this HTML

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dd1">Dropdown 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dd1" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dd2">Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dd2" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

NOTE:

- just the the JS did not work for me.
- **data-toggle**, bootstrap seems to use this to identify which `<ul>` to toggle based on class name.
- used that in combination with Paul Roub's answer to override the default behavior.